# Is it bad practice to pass your global state to functions outside of your functional components in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use functional components. If I import global state (either through Context API or Redux) into a functional component, if the global state changes, the function component will re-render and the functions that are inside it will be re-created. And yes, I know how to prevent this with useMemo and useCallback...etc.

Whenever I write a pure function I try to place it's definition outside of the functional component to prevent the need for it to be re-created on subsequent renders. Many of the functions I have to write inside of these functional components rely on state from either a global store or local component state and so I must define them within the functional component itself.

My question has 2 considerations; performance, best practice.

**Would it be bad practice to define my functions that rely on state (either global or local) outside of the functional component itself and pass the state needed as a parameter to that function? If so, why?**

A follow up question, would the performance increase of doing this be negligible?

A contrived example of what I'm talking about

```
const coolFunction = (value, setValue) => {
    // do some stuff with value
    const newValue = value++;
    setValue(newValue);
}

const anotherFunction = (state, dispatch) => {
    // change state
    const updatedValue = state * 7;
    dispatch ({
        type: "UPDATE",
        payload: updatedValue
    });
} 

const SomeComponent = () => {
    const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState();
    const {globalValue, updateGlobalValue} = useContext(GlobalContext);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <View>
            <Button onPress={{() => coolFunction(someValue, setSomeValue)}}>
                local state
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={{() => coolFunction(globalValue, dispatch)}}>
                global state
            </Button>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason not to do this. If they are indeed pure functions, defining them outside the scope of the component does save the component the overhead of recreating the function. In most cases, this isn't enormous, and if your component is re-rendered a lot, there are probably other problems to focus on. A bonus to this, or maybe even the main benefit, is that it potentially makes your component easier to read and unit test because you have increased your separation of concerns.

The performance is practically identical, as in, you will almost certainly never see the difference. In both cases, you're passing a reference to an object; just because one object has more data inside it doesn't make passing the reference any heavier. Accessing objects by key is an O(1) operation, meaning it will always be a single operation per action.

Passing a state value and setter to a function is just the same as passing them to another component as a prop; the component is, at the end of the day, just another function. This doesn't incur any extra overhead.

Comment: Solid answer Abe. Let me leave this open just a bit so I can hear others articulate their answers too.